# OpenSource Projects - Is there a site which lists projects that need more developers?

Tags: open-source, project

Do any of you know of a website which lists open source projects which are in need of help?

Let me elaborate, I would like to work on another open source project (I already work on a couple), however, it would be nice to have a site which lists lots of OS projects, their aims, deadlines, workload, how many more developers they are in need of etc.

Of course, I could just pick a topic I'm interested in, find an OS project and then work on it. However, it would be nice to see a diversified list of projects, primarily because some little known awesome projects get little attention and big projects such as jQuery forks, adium, gimp etc. etc. get a lot of attention because they are well known (and of course because they are great) and thus get a lot of developers working on them.

It would be nice to see some little known projects getting more attention and thus hopefully drawing some people to work on them.

Currently there are many websites hosting open source projects, such as github, sourceforge, google code etc.  A website to centralise all of this into one place and categorise it would be awesome.

Comment: SF has their 'help wanted' page, FWIW - http://sourceforge.net/people/

Comment: Hey, indeed, I know of this. But not all opensource projects are on SourceForge....a lot are on github, google code etc. :-)

Comment: Make one. An open source one. Kill two birds with one stone ;)

Comment: Try http://www.codetriage.com , for Github projects.

Comment: I would recommend against doing it like this.  Scratch your own itch - find a project where your work will benefit you too, as this will make a difference when the initial enthusiasm wears off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single central depository of open source projects that need help. And probably never will be due to the size and diversity of developers.

But if you are looking for a project to work on, that would be a good question to ask.

Comment: I'm not looking for a central depository(i.e. where project code is hosted, forums etc.) I'm just looking for a site which has a categorised listing of projects which need help on and for smaller projects to get more attention etc.

Projects can stay on sourceforge, github etc. but it would be nice to have a website to collate all of the projects together via some api or something similar.

"But if you are looking for a project to work on, that would be a good question to ask. " This is not my point at all. Case in point.

Comment: There isn't *one* - that was my point. I agree it would be nice.

Comment: Oh, ok. Agreed. It's a shame. :-)

Comment: If you think about it, you have good tools to search for projects that you might have an interest in working on... Use Google/Bing Search, Ohloh, CodePlex, Github, SourceForge, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is somewhat related:

http://issuetriage.herokuapp.com

Get an email for projects with open issues on github.

Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Is'nt [OHLOH](http://www.ohloh.net/) doing something similar?

Comment: I like OHLOH, it's good for looking at a projects contributors, projects costs estimates, demographics and to look at ratings and reviews etc. However, it doesn't say whether a project is in need of help etc.

And the projects aren't categorised and the biggest projects go to the top of the list.

Answer (score 1):

There is openhatch.org, it scans bug trackers to finds things to do.